# Merge python lists and return json

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two python lists:

```
cols = ['InfoKey', 'InfoData']
```

and

```
vals = ['Row 1: [LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE, Standard]', 'Row 2: [RELEASE, 15.00.04.01]', 'Row 3: [VERSION, 15.00.04.01]']
```

How do I merge them and return a JSON of the type:

```
{
"data": [{
        "Infokey": "LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE",
        "InfoData": "Standard"
    },
    {
        "Infokey": "RELEASE",
        "InfoData": "15.00 .04 .01"
    },
    {
        "Infokey": "VERSION",
        "InfoData": "15.00 .04 .01"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: You should post your own code attempt, and clearly explain where you are stuck. I admit that this problem is slightly tricky because the inner strings like `LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE` and `Standard` aren't quoted. Presumably, they never contain quotes, commas, or square brackets, otherwise it will be _very_ difficult to parse the data correctly.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
import json
l = []
for v in vals:
    info = v.split(': ')[1].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    key, data = info.split(', ')
    d = {}
    d["InfoKey"] = key
    d["InfoData"] = data
    l.append(d)

json_dict = {"data": l}

print json.dumps(json_dict)
```

RESULT:

```
{"data": [{"InfoData": "Standard", "InfoKey": "LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE"}, {"InfoData": "15.00.04.01", "InfoKey": "RELEASE"}, {"InfoData": "15.00.04.01", "InfoKey": "VERSION"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @PM said, this depends heavily on the data format being exactly as described.

```
import json

cols = ['InfoKey', 'InfoData']
vals = [
    'Row 1: [LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE, Standard]',
    'Row 2: [RELEASE, 15.00.04.01]',
    'Row 3: [VERSION, 15.00.04.01]'
]

master = []

for item in vals:
    data = item[item.find('[')+1:item.find(']')]
    parts = data.split(',')
    master.append({cols[0]: parts[0].strip(),
        cols[1]: parts[1].strip()})

print json.dumps({'data': master})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `regex` here to extract the string between `[...]`. Here's the *Sample Example*:

```
>>> import re
>>> vals = ['Row 1: [LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE, Standard]', 'Row 2: [RELEASE, 15.00.04.01]', 'Row 3: [VERSION, 15.00.04.01]']
>>> for s in vals:
...     a, b = re.findall('\[([^"]*)\]', s)[0].split(', ')
...     print('Infokey: ', a)
...     print('InfoData: ', b)
...
Infokey:  LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE
InfoData:  Standard
Infokey:  RELEASE
InfoData:  15.00.04.01
Infokey:  VERSION
InfoData:  15.00.04.01
```

*PS: You need to store the output I am printing on the console to a `dict`, and append each of the dict object to the list. I am leaving it for you to do it.*

Answer (score 0):

This will also work

```
cols = ['InfoKey', 'InfoData']
vals = ['Row 1: [LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE, Standard]', 'Row 2: [RELEASE, 15.00.04.01]', 'Row 3: [VERSION, 15.00.04.01]']
myData = []
for v in vals:
    v = v.split(': ')[1].split(', ')
    myData.append(dict(zip(cols, [v[0][1:], v[1][:-1]])))
json_data = json.dumps({'data':myData})
print(json_data)
```

Output:

```
{"data": [{"InfoKey": "LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE", "InfoData": "Standard"}, {"InfoKey": "RELEASE", "InfoData": "15.00.04.01"}, {"InfoKey": "VERSION", "InfoData": "15.00.04.01"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below presumes that the data in `vals` is safe, i.e., the inner strings like `LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE` and `Standard` *never* contain commas or square brackets.

We simply parse the strings using the `str.split` method coupled with `str.strip` to get rid of unwanted spaces. Then we can turn into dictionaries by zipping with the keys contained in `cols`.

```
import json

cols = ['InfoKey', 'InfoData']

vals = [
    'Row 1: [LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE, Standard]', 
    'Row 2: [RELEASE, 15.00.04.01]', 
    'Row 3: [VERSION, 15.00.04.01]'
]

data = []
for line in vals:
    _, lst = line.split(':')
    a = [u.strip() for u in lst.strip()[1:-1].split(',')]
    data.append(dict(zip(cols, a)))

json_obj = {'data': data}
print(json.dumps(json_obj, indent=4))
```

**output**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "InfoKey": "LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE",
            "InfoData": "Standard"
        },
        {
            "InfoKey": "RELEASE",
            "InfoData": "15.00.04.01"
        },
        {
            "InfoKey": "VERSION",
            "InfoData": "15.00.04.01"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Of course, we *could* create `data` using a list comprehension, but I think you'll agree that the previous version is *far* more readable. :)

```
data = [dict(zip(cols, (u.strip() for u in line.split(':')[1].strip()[1:-1].split(',')))) for line in vals]
```